# Observable of array with filter using Angular 5 with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5

I'm creating a simple forum.

I'm looking to filter the posts. I have some trouble with .pipe and .filter in RxJS.

I'm trying to:

- Retrieve the list of in-memory-api posts from `api/posts`, which when used with http.get it returns an `Observable<Post[]>`
- Iterate through each `Post` in the `Observable<Post[]>` and filter it so it only selects, says, each post with an id of `1` (only one post with id `1` exists).
- Log to the console any errors or if the function had success

The `filter` does not select each individual piece in the `Post[]` array, but instead selects `Post[]` itself.

**My code:**

```
getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {

  // Sets the url to the service's postsUrl
  const url = this.postsUrl;

  // The http.get returns an Observable<Post[]>
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(url)
    .pipe(
      filter(
        post: Post => post.id == 1
      ),
      // Log posts were fetched
      tap(posts => console.log('Posts fetched.')),
      // Error handling
      catchError(this.handleError('getPosts', []))
    );
 }
```

**My error:**

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Post[]'
```

In all examples I've looked at, the filter does not have this issue. I'm thinking it *should* iterate through all values in the `Post[]`, array, so I can access it as a `Post` type.

---

**Edit after answer**

My final code, based on the accepted answer, looks like this:

In `posts.service.ts`:

```
getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {

  const url = this.postsUrl;

  // Return the observable with array of Posts
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(url)
    .pipe(
      // Log posts were fetched
      tap(posts => console.log('Posts fetched.')),
      // Error handling
      catchError(this.handleError('getPosts', []))
    );

}
```

In `posts.component.ts`:

```
private getPosts(): void {
  this.service.getPosts()
    // Map posts to a filtered version
    .map(
      posts => posts.filter(
        post => post.from_board_id == this.from_board_id
      )
    )
    // Subscribe it
    .subscribe(
      posts => this.posts = posts
    )
  ;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observables are stream of values. You are saying to RXJS that you are going to receive an stream of `Post[]`, in other words, an `Array<Post>`.

If you wanna filter the array, you may do something like:

```
 return this.http.get<Post[]>(url).map(posts => posts.filter(post => post.id === 1))
```

Comment: My edit above shows my final code using what you showed with a few changes on the filter and code layout. Thanks!