# Cannot reach property of object AngularFire2/Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I added a search bar to my project, and took the code from ionic docs

```
 getItems(ev: any) {

    this.initializeItems();

    const val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.pipe(filter(item => {
        console.log(item);
        let t = item.title;
        return (t.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      }))
    }
  }
```

This is how I'm initializing the items

```
initializeItems(){
    this.items = this.newslist;
  }
```

And in the constructor

```
this.newslist = afDB.list('information/news', (ref) => ref.orderByChild('inverteddatetime')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => 
          actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
        )
      );
```

The error that I'm getting is at `let t = item.title;` where "title" is underlined red with the message

> Property "title" does not exist on type {}

When I log item in `console.log(item);` I get the correct results back though with their appropriate properties:

```
    (2) [{…}, {…}] 
0:{
datetime:"Saturday, June 23, 2018 12:28 AM"
image:"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4..."
inverteddatetime:-1529703181246
key:"-LFdPXgxgAQA1RVnGmMD"
subtitle:"Water can cause problems, be wary of the things."
text:"Water quality is a subject that’s been big news lately. Residents of Flint, Michigan are suffering from toxic levels of lead in ..."
title:"12 Toxins in Your Drinking Water"
}

1 : {key: "-LFXmks2UICxqTNkicNv", datetime: "Thursday, June 21, 2018 5:35 PM",  subtitle: "Unfortunate problems", …} length : 2
    __proto__ : Array(0)
```

Data Structure:
[Firebase Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvlHv.png) (I don't have enough reputation to display it on the thread)

I have a simple question, I don't understand why I can't reach the property "title" of the item although when I log it it shows all items and their properties. Is it because it's returning JSON and I should map it to an array?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting and also what you see in console log?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes of course, edited.

Comment: So wait your console log lists array with objects that have subtitle but not title property, can you clarify what do you mean console returns proper data for you?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes my bad, I did not expand the result, the console log does show title just like it shows subtitle and datetime which are properties of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is type error that occurs since typescript is not “aware” of your object’s (“item” in this case) data shape.
Normally you would want to type it and thus resolve it, like this:

```
let t = (item as any).title
```

But in your case here it seems like you are trying to apply filter similarly how someone did that in this issue:
[Observable of array with filter using Angular 5 with RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385805/observable-of-array-with-filter-using-angular-5-with-rxjs)

Your solution should be 1:1 similar: apply .map onto the observable you have (this.items.map( etc ) )

Like this:

```
getItems(ev: any) {

    this.initializeItems();

    const val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != “”) {
      this.items = this.items.map( items => items.filter( item => :::your filter condition here:::))
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked in terms of title no longer displaying an error, but now when I console log t it shows "undefined". I edited the question so that you can see one of the items' full properties.

Comment: Ok then can you help me understand very clearly - when you console log exactly “item” (not itemS) what do you get? you are getting array of objects?

Comment: Yes exactly. "item" is returning an array of objects

Comment: Sorry not sure my other comment went through, can you console.log(this.items) please

Comment: console.log(this.items) returns the following: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: FilterOperator}
operator
:
FilterOperator {predicate: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source
:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Ok something is still “off” here, can you share which rxjs version you are using and which angular

Comment: Of course, "rxjs": "^6.2.0", "@angular/cli": "^6.0.5", "@angular/common": "5.2.10"

Comment: And AngularFire - which version is it?

Comment: And the last thing;) can you share data structure you have in firebase? Dont need exact data but its structure

Comment: Of course, I updated my question with the data structure. And this is the version of angularefire2, "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",

Comment: Thank you so much you've been helping me thus far understand the entire thing, unfortunately using your current code it returns the error "this.items.map is not a function", not sure what to do at this point

Comment: Nevermind, it worked :) I just had to import map import 'rxjs/add/operator/map', can't thank you enough man!

Comment: Hehe glad it worked, refreshed my knowledge as well!